# I have an error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Emm... I'm Mexican, my English isn't good, but I need help, the problem is:

I can't see my apps, when I try it, I see this:
[image]
Another thing:
When I try to use `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade` the console closes.

I don't know if this problem is related. This problem appeared 3 or 2 days ago, I installed ubuntu 14.04 a... one week ago maybe

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands:

```
rm ~/.cache/software-center -R
```

and then

```
unity --reset &
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Why would this help? The problem isn't with *installing* apps (and Unity does appear). Also, if `rm ~/.cache/software-center -R` is typed just a little wrong--if someone accidentally types a space (or presses enter) just after the `~` or the first `/`--this will delete their whole home folder, including all their documents! (This is not merely theoretical; it actually happens to people from time to time.) Therefore, I recommend always explaining what recursive delete commands do so people know to be careful (and consider `cd ~/.cache && rm -r software-center` which is less prone to error).

Comment: I had this problem before too and this solved my problem.